# Different Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom between pbkrtest and emmeans

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

The `Days` variable of the `sleepstudy` dataset is numerical. Therefore it corresponds to a slope in the model `M1: Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject)`. Let's test the `Days` effect by comparing `M1` to `M0: Reaction ~ (1|Subject)` with the `pbkrtest` package:

```
library(lme4)
data("sleepstudy")
M1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)

library(pbkrtest)
M0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ (1 | Subject), data=sleepstudy)
```

then we get 161 Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom:

```
> KRmodcomp(M1, M0)
F-test with Kenward-Roger approximation; computing time: 0.30 sec.
large : Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
small : Reaction ~ (1 | Subject)
       stat   ndf   ddf F.scaling   p.value    
Ftest 169.4   1.0 161.0         1 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

But when we test the `Days` effect with `emmeans`, we get 17 degrees of freedom:

```
> library(emmeans)
> emmeans(M1, ~ Days)
 Days   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  4.5 298.5079 9.049936 17 279.4142 317.6016

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

Shouldn't we get the same number of degrees of freedom? Why do they differ? Both procedures test the nullity of the slope, don't they?

Comment: I think **emmeans** is returning the estimated marginal mean at the mean of Days.  You can see that Days is at 4.5 in the output, which is the mean of the values it takes (0-9).  [This part of the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html#numeric) might help clarify how **emmeans** works with numeric variables.

Comment: I've just observed that `emtrends(M1, ~Days, var="Days")` gives 161 DOF. I don't know what is this output of `emmeans()`.

Comment: That's an odd one. :-)  I think it's the estimated slope of the "Days" line when Days is set to its mean.  I use `emtrends` most often for getting estimates of slopes for different groups when fitting a "separate slopes" model.

Comment: That’s exactly right @aosmith, but in this case the slope is the same at any value of `Day`. The 161 df matches because the same hypothesis is being tested. The EMM is not the same as the slope — different hypothesis, different d.f.